# Fast way to find one solution to an under-determined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

What is a fast way to compute one possible solution to the under-determined system of linear equations?

Given $Ax=b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. What is a fast way to compute one $x^*$ such that $Ax^*=b$?

Note: I need only one such solution. There can be many solutions to the system.

**Edit**: I am looking for a computer algorithm. In MATLAB, one can use " \ " or `mldivide` function to a solution to linear equation but it is slow since it uses QR decomposition to solve the system. Are there any other faster methods?

Comment: How are you doing this? Would you be looking at the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix (computer output)? Or you only have pen and paper? Something else?

Comment: I am looking for a computer algorithm. In MATLAB, one can use " \ " or `mldivide` function to a solution to linear equation but it is slow since it uses QR decomposition to solve the system. Are there any other faster methods?

Comment: If a solution exists, then $b $ is a linear combination of columns of $A $. The coefficients of linear dependence (which will determine a particular solution to the system) will be in the corresponding column of the reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix. The issue I guess is then to 'match' these coefficients with the corresponding columns from $A $ (and calculate tge sum). This is easily done by inspection, as to an algorithm I am not sure.

Comment: Do you want *fast* or do you want *good*? :-)  Using orthogonal transformations as in a QR decomposition is recommended when the best accuracy is needed.  A solution is perhaps more quickly obtained (assuming real floating point arithmetic) by Gaussian elimination (the reduced row echelon form mentioned by @AnyAD), but solutions to large systems can suffer from an accumulation of rounding errors.  Hence the tradeoff between speed and precision.

Comment: Ok, So, QR decomposition is a good choice you say

Comment: Just use one of the libraries I mentioned. It uses the QR decomp but it multiplies by a random matrix and samples with the FFT.  It is much faster than the QR decomp your are calling from matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the algorithms that Matlab provides are fastest because mldivide checks for a number of cases. My Matlab license ran out, however, there is something called a subsampled [randomized Fourier Transform.](https://github.com/JuliaMatrices/LowRankApprox.jl)  There is a Julia library there. That is probably no what you want. The source code is in it and it is based on Matlab syntax.  Julia by itself is at least 10x faster than Matlab anyways.  The time complexity is far better. If you read it.

> This package has been developed with performance in mind, and early
>   tests have shown large speedups over similar codes written in MATLAB
>   and Python (and even some in Fortran and C). For example, computing an
>   ID of a Hilbert matrix of order 1024 to relative precision ~1e-15
>   takes:
>
> - ~0.02 s using LowRankApprox in Julia
> - ~0.07 s using SciPy in Python(calling a Fortran backend; see PyMatrixID)
> - ~0.3 s in MATLAB

So it is 15x faster, however this discounts the method it is using which is $\mathcal{O}(m \cdot n \log(k))$ instead of a QR decomp like you said which is  $\mathcal{O}(n^{3})$ I believe

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of classical **iterative** methods you can use. [On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Linear_systems), you will find a list of methods with more insight. These methods are rather standard by now, and most of them already have an implementation in MATLAB.

A comment on the randomized Fourier Transform mentioned above by RHowe: Since this uses Tensor compression methods, the method is faster than the iterative methods, and a lot faster for large matrices.

However, the linked source code is written in Julia, and Tensor compression methods tend to be hard and time-consuming to implement from scratch. 
If you are interested in these methods, I gladly forward you the link to the **TT-Toolbox**. There is a [MATLAB version](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46312-oseledets-tt-toolbox) and a (more up-to-date) [Python version](https://github.com/oseledets/ttpy). The TT toolbox is developed by a leading research group in the Skolkovo Technical University, sometimes dubbed the "Russian MIT".

Answer (score 0):

You could add $n-m$ rows to $A$ to create $A' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and add a corresponding number of $0$ entries (or any value you like) to $b$ to create $b'$, and then solve

$A'x = b'$

But you have to make sure that the new rows you add to $A$ are linearly independent of the existing rows and of each other, so as to ensure that $A'$ has a non-zero determinant.

Comment: How fast is determining $n-m$ linearly independent rows and then solving it?